# Differential equation system involving square.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How could I approach solving a system of differential equations which looks like this?

$$\cases{Df = g\\f^2=Dg}$$

Comment: So $D(D(f))=f^2$?

Comment: Assuming $D$ is 1-dimensional. then differentiate 1st equation. Substitute for $g$. Multiply by $f'$ and integrate to get nasty 1st order equation which is integratable in terms of elliptic integrals. Alternative put $f''=f^2$ into wolfram alpha to get a simpler expression in terms of elliptic integrals .

Comment: @user121049: How can I read about these elliptic integrals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D=\dfrac{d}{dx}$, you have:
$$\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)=f(x)^2$$
So the solution is:
$$f(x)=6WeierstrassP(x+c1,0,c2)$$
where WeierstrassP(a,b,c) is the Weierstrass elliptic function.
In more dimensions the solution is similar.

Comment: Thank you very much! Where can I read more about these curious *elliptic functions*?

Comment: @mathreadler: this is alink useful for an introduction: http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/~me350/Conferences/Burnhandout.pdf

Answer (score 1):

After elimination of $g$ you get

$$f''=f^2$$ which you can rewrite

$$f'f''=f^2f'$$ and integrate as

$$3f'^2=2f^3+C.$$

Then

$$\int\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt{2f^3+C}}df=x+C'.$$

The integral on the left has no simple closed-form.

Comment: where does the $x$ come from? what happens in last step?

Comment: Yes, but what operation manages to summon it?

Comment: @mathreadler: fixed.